# I installed latest kernel version on Kubuntu but it doesn't appear on grub list

Tags: kernel, grub2, kubuntu

I installed the latest kernel version (3.0.0-15) through the Muon package manager of Kubuntu 11.10 but when I reboot the system it doesn't appear on grub list so I can use only the 3.0.0-12 kernel version. Synaptic reports that it's installed the kernel 3.0.0-14 version too but it doesn't appear too. The 3.0.0-14 and 3.0.0-15 versions didn't have the kernel image installed so I tried to install them but they don't appear on grub list in any case. Any idea?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to update the grub list. I am not sure whether `sudo update-grub` is all you need.

Comment: Please post your /boot/grub/grub.cfg and the output of `ls /boot/`

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

Earlier with the Kubuntu: http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3104599.0

The package manager should do this by default. Looking old logs:

> Log of sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  Sat Dec 10 21:43:55 2011
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   linux-image-3.0.0-14-generic
>
> Setting up linux-image-3.0.0-14-generic (3.0.0-14.23) ... Running
>   depmod. update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
>
> run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub
>   3.0.0-14-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic Generating grub.cfg ...

man update-initramfs:

> NAME
>          update-initramfs - generate an initramfs image
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          update-initramfs -c|-d|-u [-k version] [-t] [-v] [-b] [-h]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The  update-initramfs  script  manages  your initramfs images on your local box.  It keeps track of the
>          existing initramfs archives in /boot.  There are three modes of operation  create,  update  or  delete.
>          You must at least specify one of those modes.
>
> ```
>    -u    This mode updates an existing initramfs.
> ```

Comment: I tried to do it but unfortunately it doesn't work :(